# How to check if a string passed as argument is a modifiable string

Tags: c, string, assert, undefined-behavior, string-literals

The question is pretty much in the title.

The code

```
void modify_str(char* str){
    
    if(strlen(str) > 5) {
       str[5] = 'x';
    }
}
```

Will invoke undefined behavior if a string literal is passed as argument, *i.e.*:

```
modify_str("some text");
```

Or

```
char *str = "some text";
modify_str(str);
```

Is there any way to assert at runtime that a string passed as argument is not a string literal, but a modifiable string?

Comment: @anastaciu Just declare pointers to string literals with the qualifier const.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals in C have type `char []` so there's no standard-compliant way of doing this.

Some compilers however have flags which can change the type of string literals to `const char []` so that you would get a warning for code like this.

If you're using gcc, add the `-Wwrite-strings` flag to make string literals have type `const char []`.  Then you'll get a warning like this:

```
x1.c: In function ‘main’:
x1.c:14:16: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘modify_str’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
     modify_str("some text");
                ^~~~~~~~~~~
x1.c:4:23: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
 void modify_str(char* str){
                 ~~~~~~^~~
```

Comment: Then combined with `-Werror=discarded-qualifiers` we even get an error from...

Comment: The most portable way to do this is just always assign the literal to a `const char *` pointer first and pass that as your argument. You'll get a warning on most compilers by default without any special flags required. E.g. `const char *pArg = "some text"; modify_str(pArg);`

Comment: Assigning to const is definitely a good pro-active measure to take, but the compiler options are a good way to enforce that you (and anyone else who touches the code) take the measure.